# Html video background

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use a video as a background for the first section. However,I am not able to set it to full screen.

here is part of the code:

```css
section {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.homepage {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.vid {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.7;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: black;" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
  <section class="homepage">
    <div class="vid">
      <video src="b.mp4" autoplay loop muted plays-inline type="video/mp4"></video>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I set min width and min height for the video to 100%. So it should fill the screen regardless of the screen size.Instead, it filled only about 2/3 of the supposed width and 3/4 of the supposed height

Comment: Try (a) **not** scattering ` characters across your source code, (b) Using the [live demo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) feature of the question editor, and (c) describing what happens instead of only what doesn't happen

Answer (score 0):

- `video` should be absolute 100%, not its parent `.vid` (actually, remove `<div class="vid">` if not necessary)
- `video` should be 100% width/height, not min-width/height

```css
* { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

section {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.homepage {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.vid video { /* fix this selector */
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.7;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; /* not min-width */
  height: 100%; /* not min-width */
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: black;" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
  <section class="homepage">
    <div class="vid">
      <video src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" autoplay loop muted plays-inline type="video/mp4"></video>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```